# Xamarin.Forms Deleting Files at Runtime iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I need to store a byte[] in memory. I need to access it later. The byte[] represents a video. The following code will allow the file to be written to memory, as well as accessed from memory. When the remove method shown below is called, it can still be accessed later.

I have checked that the pathname is the same.

```
        public void StoreVideo(byte[] video, string filename)
        {
            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var directoryname = Path.Combine(documents, "Videos");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryname);
            var path = Path.Combine(directoryname, filename);
            File.WriteAllBytes(path, video);
        }

        public void RemoveVideo(string filename)
        {
            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var directoryname = Path.Combine(documents, "Videos");
            var path = Path.Combine(directoryname, filename);
            File.Delete(filename);
        }

        public byte[] GetVideo(string filename)
        {
            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var directoryname = Path.Combine(documents, "Videos");
            var path = Path.Combine(directoryname, filename);

            if(File.Exists(path))
            {
                return File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: File.Delete should work normally on user writable folders.  Have you checked for any exceptions thrown?  What about using File.Exists to check after the File.Delete call?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That gives even more strange behavior. Assigning File.Exists(filename) to a bool  as the last line in RemoveVideo gives the result "false".

Comment: The strange part about this is that GetVideo Still Works after this call. These methods are called in the order they are listed above

Comment: I've found the answer. It was being made and returned via the path. Whereas I accidentally was deleting it via the filename.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this was just a small brain fart on the path being passed to the File.Delete method. However for those who run into this you should be aware that File.Delete DOES NOT throw any exception if it cannot delete the file. It should be good practice to wrap the File.Delete method a check for File.Exists